# How to add more than one vendor's product in the cart.?

Tags: wordpress, dokan

Hello i am using Multivendor dokan plugin.
when i add 2 product in cart from different  vendor i receive  this message "Sorry you cant add more than one vendor's product in the cart "

any body can help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Just go to Setting > General > Enable Single Seller Mode Turn it to On/Off based on your need